# get first 3 alphanumeric characters (only numbers or letters)

Tags: mysql

I have a table which holds a field, `title`, I need to get first 3 alphanumeric characters of each `title`. Some of the values of `title` have `",',\t,\n,` or whitespace prepended - this should be ignored.

```
+--------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------+
| id     | title                                   | desired output      | 
+--------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------+
|  1     | "abcd"                                  | abc                 | 
|  2     | 'lostworld                              | los                 | 
|  3     | \tsonof                                 | son                 | 
|  4     |  12amrt                                 | 12a                 | 
+--------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

`desired output` is the output I am looking for.  If anyone can suggest generic query which can handle all cases that would be great.

Looking for solution using MySQL only.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use a regex [user-defined function](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp).

The built-in regexp functions only support matching; not string replacing like you want here

Comment: I don't think metalfight needs any string replacing - the question sounds like they just want to output (display) the first 3 alphanumeric characters, not save them back to the database.

Comment: Right, but the column the OP wants doesn't exist. In order to create a dynamic column using a regular expression string replacement on an existing column. MySQL doesn't support regexp string replacement out of the box.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean; the inbuilt function [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) will only tell you if a there is a match or not, but the OP will need to find the matched substring.